# VSCode is stuck pushing content to my GitHub repo

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

When I try to push changes to my online repo, the **sync** icon on the left of the status bar doesn't stop rotating.

OS: Windows 10

VSCode ver: 1.58

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Working now

The solution was to manually run `git push` from the terminal. Thereafter, git integration in VSCode works.

Comment: I wish one day VSCode will have more seemless GIT and FTP features. ^^

Comment: I observe that the first time I do a "git push" from the command line, I need to choose between 1) web browser auth or 2) personal token auth. And the process hangs while waiting for my choice. Probably that's the reason the "Sync" action fails for the first time. It's a pity that it doesn't show some kind of output, either as a popup and/or in the Git console.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue,
After closing the COMMIT_EDITMSG window
it was committed.

Comment: Thanks @Nick!  your answer was the correct one for me.

Comment: This worked for me. But putting a commit message was necessary, It did not work if I left commit message as blank.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio doesn't output Git remote error so, first of all, I would check if credentials/remote is correctly set.

Many VCS providers are switching from user/password to SSH keys and allowing read/write operations only with SSH keys the that repository gets switched. If this is the case, you would not even be able to switch branch or pull.

If this is your case, in Visual Studio go to Git/Manage Remotes and update the clone link.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I've decided to commit from terminal. The command `git add --all` added my new files. After this, icon 'Commit' started work correctly. (But you can also type `git commit` by yourself).
I hope, It'll help somebody

Answer (score 0):

### Use SSH key pair

1. Generate an SSH key pair using ssh-keygen command with your email address as a label.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

2. Add your public key to your Git account.

   - Copy your public key to your clipboard using the following command(if you're in linux):

```
xclip -sel clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

```
-   Go to your Git account settings and click on “SSH and GPG keys”.
-   Click on “New SSH key” or “Add SSH key”.
-   Paste your public key into the “Key” field and click on “Add SSH key”.
```

3. Update your remote URL to use SSH instead of HTTPS.

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/repo.git
```

4. Test your connection by running `ssh -T git@github.com`.
5. Push your changes using `git push`.

hope this helps